# Como puedo obtener los ultimos datos de una tabla en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esta es mi tabla, quiero obtener el ultimo registro el cual es (010) pero tiene varias filas y quiero obtener todas las filas que tengan dicho numero

Mi tabla tiene un número de factura en este caso (010) la cual es este ejemplo tiene varios registros (filas) el nombre de dicha columna es `num_fac` y es de valor incrementable, usando NetBeans como IDE he intentado lo siguiente

```
SELECT * FROM facturas ORDER BY num_fac DESC LIMIT 1
```

y sólo me arrojó un único registro

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask]; serías tan amable de mostrarnos que has intenado?

Comment: La pregunta es interesante porque requiere una query relativamente compleja, con un concepto que no es trivial en SQL. Tal vez hayas probado un ORDER BY con LIMIT 1 y no te haya funcionado como esperas. Y no nos das ni los nombres de los campos para poder ayudarte :) Por favor, modifica la pregunta y envíanos la estructura de la tabla en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Piensa que este sitio no está pensado para depurar errores, replantear casos de uso, ni resolver ejercicios escolares, el objetivo es utilizar las dudas concretas como ejemplos para ilustrar conceptos mucho más generales que sirvan para resolver dudas similares a futuros usuarios. Preferimos enseñarte a pescar que darte peces, si vemos lo que has intentado, podremos ayudarte a mejorar. Aquí se explica mucho mejor: [ask] Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Qué código has intentando? ¿qué determina que `010` es el último registro? ¿a qué llamas registro (para mi un registro es una fila)... ese punto es confuso en tu pregunta, porque no se sabe que datos quieres exactamente?.

Comment: Disculpen soy nuevo en stackoverflow , bueno primero mi tabla tiene un número de factura en este caso (010) la cual es este ejemplo tiene varios registros (filas) el nombre de dicha columna es num_fac y es de valor incrementable , usando NetBeans como IDE he intentado lo siguiente (SELECT * FROM facturas ORDER BY nun_fac DESC LIMIT 1 ) solo me arrojo un solo registro

Comment: Se podría emplear el **OFFSET** de **LIMIT** *-más detalle en: [Cláusulas limit y offset del comando select](http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/postgresqlya/temarios/descripcion.php?cod=200&punto=42&inicio=)*-, si bien lo anterior es rápido, hay que tener cuidado cuando la cantidad de filas a omitir con el **OFFSET** sea demasiado grande: *[Paginar a través del resultado](https://use-the-index-luke.com/es/sql/resultados-parciales/paginar)*

Comment: Voy a intentar con las sugerencias que me han dado, muchas gracias

Comment: @JeikerArrieta por favor arregla tu pregunta. Pone todo lo que explicaste en comentarios en ella. Usa el boton [edit] para arreglarla.

Answer (score 4):

Efectivamente, era lo que te comentaba. Te doy la solución:

```
SELECT * FROM facturas WHERE num_fac=(
    SELECT MAX(num_fac) FROM facturas
  );
```

Y ahora la explicación:

Salvo que el campo `num_fac` estuviera indexado (porque habría una copia de la tabla ordenada por este campo) la opción del ORDER BY, OFFSET y LIMIT, aunque funciona, sería la más ineficiente.

Si tuvieras que hacer este trabajo manualmente, ¿ordenarías todas las facturas para quedarte con la última? ¿O buscarías la mayor, que la encontrarías en una única pasada, y después te quedarías con los registros correspondientes a ésta?

Pues eso es precisamente lo que tiene que hacer el servidor MySQL:

- Buscar la última factura con una consulta de totales:

  `SELECT MAX(num_fac) FROM facturas`
- Seleccionar los registros que correspondan a esa factura:

  `SELECT * FROM facturas WHERE num_fac=();`

Introduciendo en los paréntesis la subconsulta anterior.

Con el `LIMIT 1`, además de sobrecargar computacionalmente al servidor, sólo te devuelve 1 registro.

Espero que te haya resultado útil, hayas visto que la lógica de las bases de datos tiene poco que ver con la de un lenguaje de programación, y te animes a estudiar Álgebra Relacional para dominar las bases de datos relacionales.

Comment: Realmente me gustó la explicación @David, si se quisiera una consulta para un rango de facturas, sería más arduo ordenarlas y usar `LIMIT rangoInferior-1, rangoSuperior-rangoInferior`, que ir viendo si la factura está dentro del rango o no.